# Run a function in another function Python

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have Gui with Pyqt5.  I have a few QLineEdit in my Gui, and when you click the button it submits the value of those variables. It's working fine. I also have a function which clears all the LineEdits. It's working fine too.

But I want that when I press Submit the variables get submitted and then cleared. Can I run a function in another function without writing it new (because then I would have to change both everytime).

My button is like this:

```
submitButton = QPushButton("Text", self) 
submitButton.triggered.connect(self.submit)
```

To achieve this can I just do it like that?

```
submitButton = QPushButton("Text", self) 
submitButton.triggered.connect(self.submit, self.clear)
```

PS: If there is a typo in my code don't worry cause my code in general is fine. I just wrote it down on my phone.

Comment: I couldn't understand why you don't create a new function to include the two functions. What it "because then I would have to change both everytime" means  ?

Comment: you don't gat an error : AttributeError: 'QPushButton' object has no attribute 'triggered'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can connect it like this :

```
submitButton = QPushButton("Text", self) 
submitButton.clicked.connect(self.submit)
submitButton.clicked.connect(self.clear)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would, instead of making one button call 2 methods make this button call 1 method that does 2 things.

```
   def do_thing(button):
      button.submit()
      button.clear()

   submitButton = QPushButton("Text", self) 
   submitButton.triggered.connect(do_thing(self))
```